Proverb 3:1 who is the father here?
Proverbs 3:1:

My son, forget not my law; but let thine heart keep my commandments.

Who is the father here?
This is the answer I get from Copilot:


You
"My son, forget not my law; but let thine heart keep my commandments" Prov 3:1;
who is the father here?
Copilot
In Proverbs 3:1, the "father" refers to the speaker of the proverb, who is traditionally understood to be King Solomon.
He is offering wisdom and guidance, addressing the reader or listener as "my son" in a fatherly manner.
This is a common literary device in the Book of Proverbs, where the speaker imparts moral and practical teachings as a father would to his child.
Is there a specific aspect of this verse or its interpretation that you're curious about?


Welcome to the group, M. Singh. Some may object that this question is opinion-based (meaning that the answer will depend on theological outlook), but I think it is valid and can should be addressed.

Following an introduction and preface (Prov 1:1-7), the book of Proverbs begins with nine (depending on how they are counted) speeches of admonition as listed below - all begin with the phrase, "My son" or a slight variation thereof.

Prov 1:8-19, Warning against the invitation of sinful men
Prov 1:20-33, Wisdom's rebuke
Prov 2:1-22, Moral benefits of Wisdom
Prov 3:1-35, Wisdom bestows well-being
Prov 4:1-27, Get wisdom at any cost
Prov 5:1-23, Warning against adultery
Prov 6:1-19, Warnings against folly
Prov 6:20-35, Warning against folly
Prov 7:1-27, Warning against the adulteress

Historically, these have been seen in various ways such as:

the ideal father giving advice to his ideal son
Solomon (as king and "father" of Israel) dispensing advice to all young men
God the Father giving advice to all men

Inasmuch as Solomon was a prophet of God who contributed to the inspired canon of Scripture (Prov 1:1, 10:1), I do not believe it is necessary to make a final choice between these alternatives - the net effect is the same - it is good advice for all men that they ignore at their moral peril.

@Dan Fefferman Proverbs were sole attributable to Solomon, who monarch of of all 12 tribes, but Solomon was not a prophet. And even though he asked to be wise which God granted, Solomon is responsible for reintroducing Paganism into the tribes. His first wife, of many, was pagan. You see what happens right after - Solomon is immediately followed by one of his staff Jeroboam, and Rehoboam his son.
Because of Rehoboam's harshness, the 10 tribes of Israel, and took Jeroboam as their king.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Based on Psalm 1, which introduces this section of the book, we deduce that the author is speaking personally not on behalf of God.

Hear, my son, your father’s instruction,
and reject not your mother’s teaching...

The phrase "my son" is used 23 times in Proverbs, always as a personal appeal of a wise human father to his son. Of course, this father is dispensing godly wisdom, and for those who believe "all scripture is God-breathed" his teaching does come from God.
This brings is to the question of whether it is truly Solomon who speaks. The answer depends on whether one accepts the traditional attribution of the Proverbs to Solomon or the view of critical scholars who believe otherwise. The Book of Proverbs begins with an affirmation of Solomon's authorship:

The proverbs of Solomon, the son of David,
king of Israel: That people may know wisdom and discipline,
may understand intelligent sayings;  May receive instruction in wise conduct,
in what is right, just and fair; That resourcefulness may be imparted to the naive,
knowledge and discretion to the young. The wise by hearing them will advance in learning,
the intelligent will gain sound guidance,  To comprehend proverb and byword,
the words of the wise and their riddles.

This settles the matter for those who hold the doctrine of biblical inerrancy. The father is Solomon, whether writing to an actual son or to people generally. However, since the nineteenth century, scholars have found reason to doubt this attribution. According to the Jewish Encyclopedia:

The ascription of the book to Solomon, in the titles and in tradition,
is without valid foundation. In the Prophets and Psalms titles are
admittedly not authoritative—they are based on the feeling or guesses
of late scribes, not on documentary evidence—and they can not be more
trustworthy here.

An introduction to the Proverbs by an authoritative Catholic source agrees:

Editing of the whole book was done in the early postexilic period, in
the view of most scholars; at that time chaps. 1–9 would have been
added as the introduction.

Conclusion: If these modern scholars are correct then the father in Proverbs 3 is not actually Solomon himself but later writer. Whether he was writing as if he were Solomon (similar to psalmists writing from the viewpoint of David) or simply as a wise father whose work was later attributed to Solomon cannot be known. In any case, the question boils down to what amounts to a theological opinion: Is the attribution of Solomonic authorship to be accepted as a matter of faith or questioned on the basis of historical-critical analysis? But based on the internal evidence we may rule out the proposition that the father here is God.

In your first sentence, do you mean Psalm 1 or Proverbs 1?
